# how to remove hidden playonlinux files remained after uninstallation?

Tags: wine, uninstall, playonlinux

I am beginner to ubuntu. I needed safari and itunes for my computer. After checking on internet I installed wine and playonlinux. As per the video tutorial I chose "install a non listed program". And then I followed the instructions. But safari was not installed only a safari.lnk file was created on the desktop. So I thought playonlinux and wine are of no use and uninstalled both the sowtware. But still I find playonlinux's virtual drives and lots of hidden drives. Should i just delete the files for complete uninstall?

Answer (score 0):

First remove `playonlinux` and all of its configuration by typing in the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge playonlinux
```

Also, since `playonlinux` depends on wine, remove wine too.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine*
```

Next, `autoremove` dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now, to find any residues left over after those commands, run the command:

```
sudo find / -type f -iname '*playonlinux*'; sudo find / -type d -iname '*playonlinux*'; sudo find / -type f -iname '*wine*'; sudo find / -type d -iname '*wine*'; sudo find / -type f -iname '*pol*'; sudo find / -type d -iname '*pol*';
```

Check the results and delete the relevant files.

**Be extra sure to not delete any system files.**