# Kunbuntu Discover Error

Tags: discover-software-center

Every time I launch Discover I get the following error:

[image]

> W: GPG error: http://deb.playonlinux.com saucy InRelease: The
> following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
> not available: NO_PUBKEY 73F0D6E88E3D6C3A E: The repository
> 'http://deb.playonlinux.com saucy InRelease' is not signed. W:
> Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is
> therefore disabled by default. W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for
> repository creation and user configuration details. E:
> http://deb.playonlinux.com saucy InRelease is not (yet) available (The
> following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
> not available: NO_PUBKEY 73F0D6E88E3D6C3A) E: The repository
> 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu lunar
> Release' does not have a Release file. W: Updating from such a
> repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
> default. W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
> configuration details. E: The repository
> 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu
> lunar Release' does not have a Release file. W: Updating from such a
> repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
> default. W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
> configuration details.

What is the fix for this?

Comment: You have bad or incomplete repositories set up on your system.  Remove the play on linux repos from your system.  Discover uses APT in the backend and that's an apt/dpkg error so.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thomas it got me in the right direction. For others this post really helped as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/821573/how-to-remove-hidden-playonlinux-files-remained-after-uninstallation